# Survival analysis time dependent input data

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am fairly new to survival analysis and I apologize if this is a trivial question, but I wasn't able to find any solution to my problem.

I'm trying to find a good model for predicting whether and when a contract for a specific product (identified by ID column) will be bought, therefore a time to event prediction. I am interested mostly in a probability, that the event will occur in 3 months. However, my data is pretty much a monthly time series. Sample of the dataset would look somewhat like this:

| ID | Time | Number of assistance calls | Number of product malfunctions | Time to fix | Contract bought |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-01 | 0 | 0 | *NA* | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-02 | 3 | 1 | 37.124 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-03 | 2 | 0 | *NA* | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-04 | 0 | 0 | *NA* | 1 |
| 2 | 2012-03 | 1 | 0 | *NA* | 0 |
| 2 | 2012-04 | 0 | 0 | *NA* | 0 |

Here's what I struggle with. I could use a survival analysis model, e.g. Cox proportional hazards model, which is able to deal with time dependent variables, but in that case it wouldn't be able to predict (1). I could also summarize the data for each ID, but that would mean losing some information contained in the data, e.g. malfunction could occur 1, 2 or 3 months before the event.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Thank you very much for any tips!

Sources:
[1] https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev.publhealth.20.1.145

Comment: Perhaps you're searching for https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=cox+proportional+hazards ?

Comment: You should be able to predict a time to failure with either a semi-parameteric or a parametric survival analysis if and only if you have numbers at risk and times to failure.You should also be able to predict the proportion of failures in a cohort of  subjects with a similar set of covariates. You would need to know the number of items at risk. You CANNOT do survival analysis if you only know the number and times of  of failures. You offer a citation to a biomedical  stats paper that deals with time-dependent covariates which would increase the data requirements which your data does have.

Comment: @IRTFM Times to failure are easily extractable from the dataset, since I have monthly data of subjects, that either end with event (Contract bought) or not, therefore are censored.
What I do not know is which model to choose. I'm looking for such model, that would be able to deal with monthly data of different lengths for each ID.  As far as I know, Cox proportional hazard model takes in time only as a number of months.

But as I said, I am fairly new to this and I aprreciate your advice.

Comment: I do not see any column that would allow inference about the number of products in service that do not experience malfunctions. I'm voting to close because there is no data or code here that would support survival analysis. Needs more details and evidence of coding effort.

Comment: @IRTFM The Contract is bought specifically for the product, not for the client and all of their products. Number of product malfunctions is an independent variable - you can think of it as a number of heart attacks a patient suffered when predicting theri survival probability, if it helps.
I probably haven't made that clear enough, sorry about that, I already edited the description. I am unable to provide you with any code, since my question is related to where am I supposed to start with the modelling, not to a specific error in the code.

Comment: I don't think you yet accept the  fact that your data description as it stands will not support any sort of survival analysis, because you do not have a way to enumerate the number of items at risk which do NOT fail. If all you have is a summary of the number of failures and perhaps some information about them, might be able to describe features about failures as a group, but you can't say anything about the RISK of failures because you do not have durations or numbers of the non-failures. (If you ever get needed info, you may also want to consider Poisson regression for multiple failures.)